# .htaccess redirect with dynamic get parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I would like to redirect all users from path /et/{wildcard} to path /direct.php?path=wildcard_value
currently i have this but this is not dynamic nor it is any passing get parameters.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/et
    RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www\.mysite\.com/direct.php [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work for you.
`RedirectMatch 301 /et/(.*) https://example.com/direct.php?path=$1`

Comment: Thank you! Simple and working solution. But if I would like to do the same with the mod rewrite?